# confuse on the shallow copy of hashtable

Tags: c#, asp.net, hashtable

I came across few articles / explanations on shallow copying and deep copy of hashtables, the more I read, the more I am confused.

```
Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
ht.Add("1", "hello");

Hashtable ht2 = new Hashtable();
ht2 = ht;                          // case1: is this shallow copy?
ht2["1"] = "H2";

Hashtable ht3 = new Hashtable(ht); // case2: is this shallow copy?
ht3["1"] = "H3";

Hashtable ht4 = new Hashtable();
ht4 = (Hashtable)ht.Clone();       // case3: is this shallow copy?
ht4["1"] = "H4";
```

- Case1: result, ht content change become same with ht2.
- Case2: result, ht content different with ht3.
- Case3: result, ht content different with ht4.

If Case2 and Case3 are shallow copying, shouldn't the result be the same as Case1?

Does this happen to List, ArrayList, etc as well?

Comment: As an aside - if you're using .NET 3.5, why are you still using `ArrayList` and `Hashtable`? Strongly prefer the generic types.

Comment: hi @JonSkeet, thx for pointing out the generic types. I already move to generic type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case 1, both `ht2` and `ht` refer to the same instance of `Hashtable`.

In cases 2 and 3, `ht3` and `ht4` refer to *different objects* created by copying the original `Hashtable` entries.

Note that even when taking a "deep" copy (creating a new mapping) you'd still be copying references. So for example:

```
var original = new Dictionary<int, StringBuilder>();
original[10] = new StringBuilder();

var copy = new Dictoinary<int, StringBuilder>(original);
copy[20] = new StringBuilder();

// We have two different maps...
Assert.IsFalse(original.ContainsKey(20));

// But they both refer to a single StringBuilder in the entry for 10...
copy[10].Append("Foo");
Assert.AreEqual("Foo", original[10].ToString());
```

Comment: i didn't aware of this behaviour until you point it out here (with a great example). thx.